# "Une pensée pour ceux dont je n’ai que très rarement pris l’occasion de remercier"

Tags: grammaire, pronoms-relatifs

Is this sentence correct ?
It seems quite heavy and I'm not sure whether my use of "dont" is valid.

Comment: L'usage est ***avoir** l'occasion de* et non ***prendre** l'occasion de* qui est une formule littéraire académique qui ne conviendra pas forcément pour le public à qui l'on s'adresse : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=je+prends+l%27occasion%2Cj%27ai+l%27occasion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cje%20prends%20l%27%20occasion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cj%27ai%20l%27%20occasion%3B%2Cc0 N.B. : déclencher la recherche si le graphique ne s'affiche pas tout seul.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Une pensée pour ceux **que j'ai** très rarement pris l’occasion de remercier

Is enough. "Dont" is used only if "ceux" is not who is "remercié", for example in:

> Une pensée pour ceux dont j'ai très rarement pris l'occasion de remercier la contribution à ce projet.

As here you thanks their contribution and not the people.

Note by the way that I removed the "n'" as there is no negation here : you actually thanks them, just not enough. If you want to add the idea that your thanks were not enough, use "trop" instead of "très":

> Une pensée pour ceux que j'ai trop rarement pris l’occasion de remercier

Comment: I do not agree with you about the *n'... que* ! It expresses that even though there were thanks, they were not enough in numbers. If you remove the negation then you also remove this idea, which I think is intended as an apology. My best try to rephrase would be to drastically change the words, as in *j'adresse une pensée à ceux que j'ai trop peu remerciés* (it even rhymes ! ahah)

Comment: I tried to stick the more possible to the OP's sentence, even if it is not perfect. Edited anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The use of **dont** is not correct here. **Dont** is the genitive case of the subordinate conjunction.
With the correct case, your sentence becomes :

> Une pensée pour ceux **que** je n’ai que très rarement pris l’occasion
>   de remercier

This sentence is correct, but might be a bit disturbing to hear (because of the **que** redundancy). If you want something more pleasant to hear, you have different options :

I think Anne Aunyme's sentence is the best :

> Une pensée pour ceux que j'ai trop rarement pris l’occasion de remercier

Another possible sentence :

> Une pensée pour ceux que je n'ai pas suffisamment remerciés

**Bonus :**

If you want to use **dont** :

> Une pensée pour ceux dont le mérite n'a pas été suffisamment reconnu.